# How to integrate terminal in Qt Creator IDE?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

Is it possible to launch terminal / command prompt with in Qt Creator IDE(just like in Visual Studio Code) ?

Comment: when, where and how do you want to launch the terminal

Comment: embedded terminal window with in IDE. like in Visual Studio code editor

Comment: How about this plugin?
https://github.com/JakeSays/QtCreatorTerminalPlugin

Answer (score 2):

If you mean, just generic terminal, or some kind of embedded terminal window, then no. If you need a terminal for your work, you need to run it separately, and independent of Qt Creator.

You can run terminal commands though, with

*ctrl-K* `!` *space* your command

Answer (score 1):

Ahem...

[image: Qt Creator terminal]

Qt Creator 4.11.0 (Based on Qt 5.14.0) / Windows 10 / Several Qt kits used.

If that's not what you need, what is it then? =)

Answer (score 0):

You can check the option "Run in terminal" in the "Run" settings (see Build & Run settings of your project Kit)

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Qt Creator 11 there is an integrated Terminal supported. See below:

[image]