# zsh: command not found: qmake However, I've installed Qt5.12.0, I can lunch the Qt Creator

Tags: qt

I've installed `Qt5.12.0` on `macOS Catalina 10.15.6` successfully. But I can't use `qmake` in the terminal. What should I do?

I've tired several commands

```
➜  ~ which qmake
qmake not found
➜  ~ qmake -qt=qt5
zsh: command not found: qmake
➜  ~ QT_SELECT=qt5 qmake
zsh: command not found: qmake
➜  ~ export QT_SELECT=qt5
➜  ~ which qmake
qmake not found
➜  ~ which qmake-qt5
qmake-qt5 not found
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like `qmake` is not in your  search path. Have you launched terminal manually or used "Open terminal" from Creator's menu? The latter it likely to have a better behaviour

Comment: @MasterAler I launched the `iTerm` manually. It works once I use the full directory of `qmake`. Although it's not a smart approach.

Comment: right-click on any project file in Qt Creator, try "Open console in...", maybe?

Comment: Do you mean in the left side bar `Edit` tab -> the root folder -> right click? I can't see `Open console in`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59400717/2846068
I cannot currently check if `qmake` is there, but that's the console I was talking about

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Instead of `qmake -version` and `qmake -project` use the full path of `qmake`.

```bash
/Users/username/Qt5.12.0/5.12.0/clang_64/bin/qmake -version
/Users/username/Qt5.12.0/5.12.0/clang_64/bin/qmake -project
```

However, it's not the optimal solution. So I try to add `alias` in `~/.zshrc`

```
vi ~/.zshrc
```

Then add the alias. I think whether the code is on the top or the bottom doesn't matter, as long as you don't put it in other code fields.

```
alias qmake="/Users/username/Qt5.12.0/5.12.0/clang_64/bin/qmake"
```

Remember to `source ~/.zshrc` to reload the configuration file and activate the changes.

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it's on the `C:\Qt\6.6.2\mingw_64\bin` directory.
I used the online installer, and there is an option to which tools you want to install
[image: QT online installer]

That´s what `6.6.2` and `mingw_64` stands for.